ts-node shadows import path with JSON files, but TypeScript does not raise issue at compile time
When the "resolveJsonModule" compiler option is specified, TypeScript appears to have very unusual behaviour if a JSON file has the same name as a TypeScript file:
myModule.json
{
  "foo": "bar"
}

myModule.ts
export function hello() {
  return 'Hello, world!';
}

elsewhere.ts
import { hello } from './myModule';

// type is `string`
const message = hello();

According to TypeScript's error checking, the function should be imported correctly, but at runtime, calling the function throws an exception, since the value is undefined.
console.log(hello);
// undefined
hello()
// TypeError: (0 , myModule_1.hello) is not a function

This seemingly happens due to TypeScript (or maybe ts-node) attempting to import the values from the JSON file of the same name, despite TypeScript giving no errors or warnings run running npx tsc --noEmit.
This is very confusing to debug, and so I would like TypeScript to give a warning if these conflicting imports exist. How can I achieve this? Is there a rule I can set in typescript-eslint, or an option I can set in tsconfig.json? I've had a hunt through the documentation, but haven't come across anything that matches my needs.

This is a (not very) known limitation of ts-node unfortunately, see ts-node#389 and ts-node#1868 for example:

when you omit the file extension from an import, node will load them in this order: .js first, then .json, then .ts

(the latter being added by ts-node, since node does not natively support TS)

this should be considered a bug though, since the module resolution is different from typescript's, and behavior between running ts-node and running tsc with node diverges.

Therefore TypeScript in itself behaves correctly: the expected tool chain tsc followed by node does load the .js file (transpiled from the .ts file) first. Unfortunately that means there will not be any TSConfig setting to check the inconsistency that is introduced by ts-node.
But the good news is that you have very easy workarounds:

explicitly add the (output) file extension, so import x from './myModule.js'; in your case
renaming .json files to avoid base name conflict (even though you probably prefer avoiding this solution for your own reasons)


Thanks for the advice. Unfortunately, I'm asking this question on behalf of a course I teach, so was hoping for something that can warn students about this pitfall (through an eslint or tsc error) to prevent them from stumbling into the issue, so this doesn't entirely answer the question. Even still, it's very helpful to know the origin of the issue.

I see. Unfortunately, there is no tool that I know of to raise such warning, as this is specific to ts-node.
